# Multivariate time series forecasting using Support Vector Regression in R

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, svm, forecasting

I have data like this:

```
pce        pop        psavert    uempmed    unemploy
507.8      198712     9.8        4.5        2944
510.9      198911     9.8        4.7        2945
516.7      199113     9.8        4.6        2958
513.3      199311     9.8        4.9        3143
518.5      199498     9.8        4.7        3066
```

I am trying to use SVM - regression to fit the data like this

```
svmRbftune <- train(unemploy ~ pce + pop + psavert + uempmed,
                    data = EconomicsTrain, method = "svmRadial",
                    tunelength = 14, trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))

svmRbfPredict <- predict(svmRbftune, EconomicsTest)
```

How can I forecast two to three steps ahead?